# HTML select or textarea

Tags: html, textarea, html-select

I'm trying to figure out how to create a test area where the user can either select from a list of items, or add to a textarea. Is this possible? Something like the following, except restrict the user to either selecting from the list, or entering into the textarea.

```
<tr>
   <td width="100" class="formNames">Frequency</td>
   <td colspan="2" class="cellColor">
      <select name="yr" class="textbox">
         <option value="0">-</option>
         <option value="30">1</option>
         <option value="30">2</option>
         <option value="30">3</option>
         <option value="30">4</option>
         <option value="30">5</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td width="10" class="formNames"> -or- </td>
   <td class="formNames">
      <input type="text" name="scheduletitle" class="textbox" value="default" />
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible to select an item from a `select` or enter text in a `textarea`? Yes.

Comment: He's asking how to allow the user to only enter data in one field and not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disable the other when data is changed in one.  Using jQuery:

```
(function(){
   var elements = $('select[name=yr],input[name=scheduletitle]');
   elements.bind('change', function(){
      var self = this;
      elements.attr('disabled', false);
      $(this).val() && elements.filter(function(){ return this != self; }).attr('disabled', true);
   }
})();
```

Comment: hi cwolves.. didn't know this was possible!! is there a way to accomplish this any other way or using mootools? thanks!

Comment: yes, but I don't know mootools, sorry :)   The idea is that you set the disabled attribute on all the other elements, preventing the user from using them.  Make sure you clear it if they wipe the data (which is what the `$(this).val()` piece is about)